# Parsing JSON data in actionscript 3

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I have a JSON response coming up as

```
[{"serial": "1", "name": "ABC" }]
```

I am using **com.adobe.serialization.JSON** class of **as3corelib** in *actionscript*. This class works perfectly in other formats of json, but in this case, after doing a *JSON.decode* to the object I am unable to get the value as obj.name

If I remove the square brackets I am getting a parsing error.

How can I parse the json in this case, I need to get the value of the key "name". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically to parse all the objects you'll need

```
// serverResponse answer from the server [String]
var jsonResponse:Object = JSON.parse(serverResponse);
for ( var object:Object in jsonResponse ){
   trace(object.name);
}
```

Well as you edited this is using : [ActionScript 3 JSON](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) and it's not just for air, you still can use it

---

And using AS3CoreLib, [here is an example](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/examples/JSONExample/JSONExample.mxml) showing how to handle the JSON, so it look like this :

```
var rawData:String = String(event.result);
var arr:Array = (JSON.decode(rawData) as Array);
for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    trace(arr[i].name);
}
```

Hope this helps, Cheers !!

Comment: Hi this is for adobe air, and am using the as3corelib.swc

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing array of json objects. You need to fetch the value like obj[0].name.

Hope it helps.